# How to hide / show CustomValidation validation messages without postback

Tags: asp.net, validation, customvalidator

**UPDATE : Figured it out..
The objects I was passing to the ValidatorHookupControl were'nt being set properly (were null). Now that they are, the messages are currectly dissapearing when the hooked up control looses it's focus.**

---

**ORIGINAL POST ..**

Hi,

I have some *ClientValidation* controls that have *ClientSideValidation* methods which work fine when validating the page..

However, how can I make it so that when a certain control that a CustomValidators clientside method kicks in and udates the validation message depending on whether the validation has passed or not. (Like the *RequiredFieldValidator or RegExValidator*).

My Customvalidators do not have their ControltoValidate properties set as some of them depend on multiple controls.

I don't want any postbacks (full or partial).

I have tried..

1. Adding an onchange attribute on dropdowns, radioboxes and checkboxes that call a helper clientside method which calls `Page_ClientValidate('GroupName')`, then setting window.location back to the control in question (as it went back to top of screen).

Using this method the args.IsValid is still being set by the ClientSideValidation method.

2. And I have tried [**ValidatorHookupControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) (control, validator) but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any thoughts..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, was passing null objects into the ValidatorHookupControl method.
Works now. Doh!